# Django logs: any tutorial to log to a file

Tags: python, django, logging, mod-python

I am working with a django project, I haven't started. The developed working on the project left. During the knowledge transfer, it was told to me that all the events are logged to the database. I don't find the database interface useful to search for logs and sometimes they don't even log(I might be wrong). I want to know, if there is an easy tutorial that explains how to enable logging in Django with minimal configuration changes.

Thank you
Bala

Comment: um what kind of logging? Django's admin logs some action link edit, creating, deleting of an object to Log model.

Comment: @Algorist: Do you mean the history in the admin? Otherwise this sounds implementation-specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about the Django admin log (the one that shows on the right side of the main page of the admin interface), you could just enable an admin model for the log itself.

Open the `admin.py` for one of your django apps and add this:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry

class LogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('content_type', 'user', 'action_time')

admin.site.register(LogEntry, LogEntryAdmin)
```

It will give you a barebones interface for looking at the log.

Remember that log is only logging whatever happens through the admin interface itself.