# Make django admin logEntry read only?

Tags: python, django, logging, django-models

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479858/) and it was very useful, but what I need is to make the `logEntry` model read-only in the admin interface. Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example from the post you mentioned, with the needed change to make the fields read-only:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry

class LogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('content_type', 'user', 'action_time')

admin.site.register(LogEntry, LogEntryAdmin)
```

This works only in Django 1.2 so it is possible you will have to upgrade your Django package.